# SqlConnection Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Всем привет.

У меня есть класс который зависит от `SqlConnection`.

В моем `DI Config` прописано:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbConnection, SqlConnection>();
```

Мне нужно свойство: `con.ServerVersion`, к которой обратиться появляется возможность только если мы не используем интерфейс при создании объекта, то-есть так:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection()
```

при котором создается строгая зависимость.

Как можно избежать строгой зависимости в этой ситуации?

Comment: По тому, что я понял я бы решал 2 способами 1). работал  бы с IDbConnection и добавил еще сторонний DbConPropertyResolver у которого мог бы спросить "что знаешь об этом IDbConnection", а он сам может быть в любой другой сборке и связываться через интерфейс IDbConPropertyResolver 2) можно улучшить 1, только не тащить его как IDbConPropertyResolver, а расширить через extensions IDbConnection, а можно прямо расширение определить в другой сборке

Comment: 3) Расширил бы интерфейс IDbConnection через наследника и сделал обертку над конкретным SqlConnection и работал бы с этим унаследованным интерфейсом там, где надо знание того, чего нет в IDbConnection

Comment: если рассматривать 3й вариант, я так понял, мы создаем строгую зависимость в  самом интерфейсе который наследует и расширяет IDbConnection??

Comment: Нет. Мы просто добавляем в интерфейс метод GetVersion или свойство ServVersion {get;}. Те, кому оно не нужно, продолжают работать с IDbConnection, а кому нужно - потребуют более конкретный интерфейс наследник. А вот уже в реализации обертки, которая реализует этот интерфейс и будет зависимость (а реализация может быть в любой сборке и местом сопоставления будет контейнер).

Comment: Извините что сотый раз переспрашиваю)
Просто хочу быть уверенным что точно понял:
1. Наследуем интерфейс IDbConnection, с одним свойством ServerVersion;
2. Реализуем этот интерфейс, полем этого класса будет
SqlConnection conection , и в конструкторе например мы его создаем, передавая строку подключения, ну и реализуем все нужные свойства и методы просто вызывая их из SqlConnection conection??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вам нужна `ServerVersion` - значит ваш код в принципе не может работать ни с чем, кроме `SqlConnection` - он же неработоспособен на других реализациях `IDbConnection`.

То, что при этом вы в коде добьетесь *видимости отсутствия* зависимости, заменив ее на каст `IDbConnection` где-то в коде - на самом деле не устранит зависимость. Просто хорошо замаскирует, и сделает проверяемой во время выполнения, а не во время компиляции (что в этом конкретном случае скорее плохо, чем хорошо).

Хотите хорошего решения - используйте Interface segregation - разделите публичный интерфейс `SqlConnection` на два

- `IDbConnection`, который будет отвечать за выполнение запросов (если он вообще будет)
- `IDbVersionProvider` - который будет отвечать предоставление версии.

IDbVersionProvider реализуйте через создание `SqlConnection` (напрямую) и извлечение из него версии.

Comment: то-есть IDbVersionProvider будет расширением IDbConnection с версией сервера и использоваться будет исключительно для этого?

Comment: @aperkot не расширением IDbConnection. Просто интерфейсом с одним методом/свойством Version. Который реализуется классом, который внутри создает SqlConnection и возвращает версию

Answer (score 2):

Имеем IDbConnection и его реализацию с чем-то, чего нет в IDbConnection, то есть зависимость от реализации. А также какой-нибудь ioC (DI). Ну и знание того, что реализация может быть в любой сборке - главное зарегистрировать в контейнере, а это можно сделать в любой сборке. Типичный вариант - контейнер прокидывается по классам-регистраторам в сборках (модулях), где каждый модуль регистрирует то, что есть у него.

Варианты решения:

1 Сторонний сервис.

Это решение "в лоб". Если IDbConnection не дает нужных данных, то мы просто создаем сервис, который выдаст нам данные для коннекта. То есть создаем интерфейс вида

```
interface IMetaDataProvider{
    int GetServerVersion(IDbConnection conn);
}
```

и делаем реализацию этого в любом месте, где есть явная зависимость, то есть в другой сборке.

```
interface MetaDataProvider : IMetaDataProvider{
    int GetServerVersion(IDbConnection conn){
        var tmp=conn as SqlConnection;
        ... достаем что нам надо
    }
}
```

и регистрируем этот сервис в IoC и где надо просто прокидываем его и клиентский код узнает у него о соединении что ему надо.

2 Расширяем IDbConnection через наследование.

Делаем наследника IDbConnection с нужными нам свойствами.

```
interface IMyDbConnection : IDbConnection {
    int ServerVersion {get;}
}
```

поскольку SqlConnection не знает про наш IMyDbConnection, то придется написать враппер.

```
class SqlConnWrapper : IMyDbConnection {

   private SqlConnection _conn;

   ...тут реализация IDbConnection с простым прокидываем к conn

    int ServerVersion => _conn.ServerVersion;
}
```

Напоминаю - враппер может быть определен в другой сборке и IoC свяжет интерфейс и реализацию
Регистрируем SqlConnWrapper для IMyDbConnection и IDbConnection (детали регистрации зависят от контейнера)

И те, кому нужно знание ServerVersion, запросят себе IMyDbConnection, где явно прочитают свойство, остальные же будут просить IDbConnection

3 Расширение IDbConnection

просто пишем extension метод для IDbConnection

```
public static class IDbConnectionEx
{
    public int GetVersion(IDbConnection conn)
    {
        var tmp = conn as SqlConnection;
        ...получаем версию
    }
}
```

тут мы обязаны иметь прямую зависимость на сборку, где определили extension, но изнутри extension мы опять же можем делать что угодно...например обратиться к глобальному DI (если есть такой), где лежит хотя бы что-то подобное IMetaDataProvider и ему делегировать запрос, а MetaDataProvider может быть в любой сборке.

Comment: спасибо за столь вычерпывающий ответ и выделенное время!